# Which ipv6 address to use for AAAA record

Tags: vps, ipv6

My [VPS provider](http://conoha.jp) provides me with one ipv4 and 17 ipv6 addresses. Is there any right or wrong ipv6 address from the 17 given to use as AAAA record ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all 17 addresses are assigned and configured, any of them (or all of them) will work.  The key is that the address is working on the server

Answer (score 3):

You use whichever IP v6 address you have assigned to your server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use address which is configured on your server interface. No another limit, it behaves same as IPv4.